# Substituir informações no R

Tags: r

Quero usar um mesmo arquivo de programação do R para outra análise e queria saber como faço para substituir, por exemplo, o nome dos atributos, usando a mesma sintaxe.
Obrigado

Comment: Por favor dê um exemplo de código e *"atributos"* (variáveis?). Tal como está a pegunta está tão geral que o mais certo é ir ser fechada.